# Recursive or error-checking mutex?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex

Until recently I considered error-checking mutexes mostly as a debugging tool with little value in correct code, but then I realized they have the property that they can replace recursive mutexes, as in:

```
void foo()
{
    int ok_to_unlock = !pthread_mutex_lock(m);
    /* do something */
    if (ok_to_unlock) pthread_mutex_unlock(m);
}
```

Note that `pthread_mutex_lock` returns 0 on success and `EDEADLK` if the caller already holds the lock. This usage has the advantage that you don't have to worry about exceeding an arbitrary recursive lock limit; the "lock count" is implicit in the call frame. In principle this idiom might perform slightly better too, since the function call to `pthread_mutex_unlock` is never made when the calling thread already held the lock.

My question is mainly then about style: does using error-checking mutexes like this detract from the clarity of the code? Are there any other reasons you wouldn't want to use them like this?

Comment: This sounds highly subjective. :)

Comment: I suppose; the question in the final sentence is a bit of a non-subjective turn though (non-style reasons this usage would be bad).

Comment: Besides style - I'd investigate the performace of a PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK. If you save a few pthread_mutex_xxx calls, it might not be worth it if it turns out error checking mutexes are e.g. 10x slower than normal or recursive mutexes

Comment: In principle the amount of work involved in error-checking and recursive mutexes is the same. Both have to identify the calling thread and compare that against an owner saved in the mutex. The difference should just be how they act when the two match (incrementing a counter or returning an error).

Answer (score 2):

> Note that `pthread_mutex_lock` returns `0` on success
>   and `EDEADLK` if the caller already holds the lock.

Your code as posted is not entirely robust, because `EDEADLK` is *not* the only possible error that might be returned. There is also `EINVAL` if the mutex has not been properly initialized.

On a slightly tangential note, David Butenhof has some [interesting warnings](http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html) about the use of recursive mutexes.

Comment: Using an uninitialized mutex results in UB, so there's no need to account for that case.

Comment: +1 for the link. An interesting piece of history. I used to agree with this view, until I understood how stdio locking and `flockfile` worked, which is a type of recursive mutex. Then I realized recursive mutexes allow you to protect the smallest unit of data manipulation, while also allowing a caller to make a larger unit of data manipulation atomic - in the case of stdio, ensuring that multiple file IO operations take place as an atomic unit.

Answer (score 1):

This is subjective, but I feel that this makes the code less clear.

Comment: Agreed--a future maintainer might rightly ask why "errors" are being returned by locks in the program, not to mention that any tools formulated to check concurrent programs for correctness might balk.

Answer (score 1):

I think that whatever performance gains you might realize would be swamped by the costs of using the error-checking mutex in the first place. However, even those costs are likely to be small, and I don't see any reason not to use this idiom. My only comment would be to use a variable name like `locked` rather than `ok_to_unlock`.

Comment: The issue with 'locked' is that the mutex *is* locked either way - the variable indicates who has responsibility for unlocking it (us or caller). Whatever you call it, the variable is true if the mutex wasn't locked until we came along, and false if it was already locked.